# Pixelated/blurry emission

Tags: emission

total beginner here so I hope I summarize my issue correctly:

so, I want to make a glowing object and for that (as far as I understood) I need to apply the emission node. However when doing so, all I get is this blurry area of pixels as shown here:

[image]

Does anyone know the cause and solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post an image of what your node tree looks like and a little more information about your scene?

Comment: Sorry, after looking at my nodes again, I realized I wrongly connected the emission node to the volume, instead of the surface of the material output. Changing it fixed the problem! Thanks anyway